# Want to get a specific Element from a json array,

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I havethe following JSON array and want to fetch a specific element from it for example the first element "long_name"

this is my JSON array:

```
({results:[{address_components:[{long_name:"Lahore", short_name:"Lahore", types:["locality", "political"]}, {long_name:"Lahore District", short_name:"Lahore District", types:["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {long_name:"Punjab", short_name:"Punjab", types:["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {long_name:"Pakistan", short_name:"PK", types:["country", "political"]}], formatted_address:"Lahore, Pakistan", geometry:{bounds:{northeast:{lat:31.6332872, lng:74.505512}, southwest:{lat:31.3342113, lng:74.1469001}}, location:{lat:31.55460609999999, lng:74.3571581}, location_type:"APPROXIMATE", viewport:{northeast:{lat:31.6332872, lng:74.505512}, southwest:{lat:31.3342113, lng:74.1469001}}}, place_id:"ChIJ2QeB5YMEGTkRYiR-zGy-OsI", types:["locality", "political"]}], status:"OK"})
```

Please help me on this..Thanks1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON results, like so

```
var results = '{"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Lahore", "short_name":"Lahore", "types":["locality", "political"]}, {"long_name":"Lahore District", "short_name":"Lahore District", "types":["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {"long_name":"Punjab", "short_name":"Punjab", "types":["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {"long_name":"Pakistan", "short_name":"PK", "types":["country", "political"]}], "formatted_address":"Lahore, Pakistan", "geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":31.6332872, "lng":74.505512}, "southwest":{"lat":31.3342113, "lng":74.1469001}}, "location":{"lat":31.55460609999999, "lng":74.3571581}, "location_type":"APPROXIMATE", "viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":31.6332872, "lng":74.505512}, "southwest":{"lat":31.3342113, "lng":74.1469001}}}, "place_id":"ChIJ2QeB5YMEGTkRYiR-zGy-OsI", "types":["locality", "political"]}], "status":"OK"}';

var json = JSON.parse(results);
alert(json.results[0].address_components[0].long_name); //will show 'Lahore'
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {results:[{address_components:[{long_name:"Lahore", short_name:"Lahore", types:["locality", "political"]}, {long_name:"Lahore District", short_name:"Lahore District", types:["administrative_area_level_2", "political"]}, {long_name:"Punjab", short_name:"Punjab", types:["administrative_area_level_1", "political"]}, {long_name:"Pakistan", short_name:"PK", types:["country", "political"]}], formatted_address:"Lahore, Pakistan", geometry:{bounds:{northeast:{lat:31.6332872, lng:74.505512}, southwest:{lat:31.3342113, lng:74.1469001}}, location:{lat:31.55460609999999, lng:74.3571581}, location_type:"APPROXIMATE", viewport:{northeast:{lat:31.6332872, lng:74.505512}, southwest:{lat:31.3342113, lng:74.1469001}}}, place_id:"ChIJ2QeB5YMEGTkRYiR-zGy-OsI", types:["locality", "political"]}], status:"OK"};

alert(data.results[0].address_components[0].long_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

A JSON object is a list of lists. In order to access lower layers you first need to parse the JSON object and create an array.
    `var jsonArray = JSON.parse(json_object);`
Then you need to create an array from the array index that you need to reach.
    `var address_components = jsonArray[0];`
Then you would need to go a step down again.
    `var long_name = address_components[0].long_name;`

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to see the exact path with the JSON all on one line. Formatting it in a more "human viewable" format renders as follows:

```
({
  results: [
    {
      address_components: [
        {
          long_name: "Lahore",
          short_name: "Lahore",
          types: [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          long_name: "Lahore District",
          short_name: "Lahore District",
          types: [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          long_name: "Punjab",
          short_name: "Punjab",
          types: [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          long_name: "Pakistan",
          short_name: "PK",
          types: [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      formatted_address: "Lahore, Pakistan",
      geometry: {
        bounds: {
          northeast: {
            lat: 31.6332872,
            lng: 74.505512
          },
          southwest: {
            lat: 31.3342113,
            lng: 74.1469001
          }
        },
        location: {
          lat: 31.55460609999999,
          lng: 74.3571581
        },
        location_type: "APPROXIMATE",
        viewport: {
          northeast: {
            lat: 31.6332872,
            lng: 74.505512
          },
          southwest: {
            lat: 31.3342113,
            lng: 74.1469001
          }
        }
      },
      place_id: "ChIJ2QeB5YMEGTkRYiR-zGy-OsI",
      types: [
        "locality",
        "political"
      ]
    }
  ],
  status: "OK"
})
```

This way you can see that the json object contains a property of results which is an array. The elements of results contain an address_components property which is also an array. The elements of address_components contain the long_name property. To access this, you would do the following, assuming you have a JSON string stored in jsonString:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var firstLongNameProperty = jsonObject.results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off you should construct a valid JSON string so you need to put quotes around your keys like so...

```
'{"results": [{"address_components": [{"long_name": "Lahore","short_name": "Lahore","types": ["locality","political"]},{"long_name": "Lahore District","short_name": "Lahore District","types": ["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name": "Punjab","short_name": "Punjab","types": ["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name": "Pakistan","short_name": "PK","types": ["country","political"]}],"formatted_address": "Lahore, Pakistan","geometry": {"bounds": {"northeast": {"lat": 31.633287,"lng": 74.50551},"southwest": {"lat": 31.334211,"lng": 74.1469}},"location": {"lat": 31.554605,"lng": 74.357155},"location_type": "APPROXIMATE","viewport": {"northeast": {"lat": 31.633287,"lng": 74.50551},"southwest": {"lat": 31.334211,"lng": 74.1469}}},"place_id": "ChIJ2QeB5YMEGTkRYiR-zGy-OsI","types": ["locality","political"]}],"status": "OK"}'
```

[**Better View JSON**](https://shrib.com/eJFKpWl8SvA0SmI)

After that you just have to parse your JSON text and append the values wherever needed

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

JavaScript

```
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
var text_div = document.getElementById('test');
for (i = 0; i < obj.results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
  text_div.innerHTML = text_div.innerHTML + obj.results[0].address_components[i].long_name + '<br>';
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9402vh66/2/)